# Tensoflow 2.12.0 does not recognize tensorflow.compiler.xla.experimental

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Using the [Bert](https://github.com/mlcommons/training/blob/master/language_model/tensorflow/bert/deferred_grad_optimizer.py#L11) code, I see this import line:

```
from tensorflow.compiler.xla.experimental.xla_sharding import xla_sharding
```

which causes this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compiler.xla.experimental'
```

Below you can see the versions and packages I have installed:

```
$ pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow                        2.12.0
tensorflow-addons                 0.20.0
tensorflow-estimator              2.12.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem      0.32.0


$ find python3.8/site-packages/ -name compiler
python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/compiler
python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/compiler
python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/xla_aot_runtime_src/tensorflow/compiler
python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/compiler
python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/include/google/protobuf/compiler
python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/compiler
python3.8/site-packages/jedi/third_party/typeshed/third_party/2and3/google/protobuf/compiler


$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

Everything looks fine, but I wonder what the problem exactly. The compiler seems to be introduced in TF-2.4.0, so 2.12.0 should be fine with that.

I tried step-by-step and see

```
>>> from tensorflow.compiler import xla
>>> from tensorflow.compiler.xla import experimental
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'experimental' from 'tensorflow.compiler.xla' (/home/mahmood/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/compiler/xla/__init__.py)
```

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tensorflow.compiler.xla.experimental` was moved to `tensorflow.python.compiler.xla.experimental` during the release of Tensorflow 2.11.0.

See the commit: [6ed611b](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/6ed611beb95124234d07053581205eb8f3a865a5):

> **Move TensorFlow xla_sharding python API from XLA to
> tensorflow/python…**
>
> …/compiler/xla
>
> This is removing a dependency from XLA to TensorFlow
>
> PiperOrigin-RevId: 477339536